# Another java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, matlab, classcastexception

I have a problem with casting a variable (see below) to a String so that it can be displayed in a GUI. Some background information: I have created a Java GUI that will run some Matlab code (using MatlabProxy) and as part of the process I am trying to update the GUI with some useful information (passed back to the GUI from Matlab) about a specific data file (that the user has chosen). The MatlabProxy "getMVariable()" function returns an object of type "double" (in my case); however, when I try to cast this to a String using

```
String text = (String) getMVariable("testInfo.freqMax");
```

I get the ClassCastException: "[D cannot be cast to java.lang.String." I also tried casting it to a String array (String[]) with no luck. I've read some posts that say something about using Array.copyOf or something about an array list, but could not make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[D` means it's a `double[]`. See [`Class#getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).

```
double[] foo = (double[]) getMVariable("testInfo.freqMax");
```

After that, it's up to you to figure out what to do with it.

Comment: This one was what I needed, though I had to modify it as follows (accordning to the Matlab Proxy wiki, which I did not know existed until now): double[] foo = ((double[]) getMVariable("testInfo.freqMax"))[0];

Answer (score 0):

If the type is `[D` then you have an `double[]` not a `double` or a `Object[]`

You need something like this.

```
Object var = getMVariable("testInfo.freqMax");
String text;
if (var instanceof double[])
   text = Arrays.toString((double[]) var);
else
   text = "" + var;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you for sure that

> getMVariable("testInfo.freqMax")

returns Double, then why not user

> getMVariable("testInfo.freqMax").toString();

Answer (score 0):

replacing that line with this code might clarify what's going on:

```
String text = "";
double[] allValues = getMVariable("testInfo.freqMax");

for(double oneValue : allValues) {
    System.out.println("adding the characters '" + oneValue + " ' to text");
    text += oneValue;
    text += " ";
}

System.out.println("after we've read all values, text has become: '" + text + "'");
```

if you're unfamiliar with the "for"-structure here, just ask :)